# Abbreviated string from MySQL 'time' field type in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have a MySQL field which stores times using the 'time' field type, such as '12:30:00' i.e. in the HH:MM:SS format.

In my PHP app I want to convert such HH:MM:SS data into a more readable string, such as '12.30pm'.

Is there any function for doing this, or will I have to do it by other means?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a machine to test it on at the moment, but I would look at: [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). I believe that the following should be what you want:

```
$print_time = date("h.ia", strtotime($sql_time));
```

Where `$print_time` is the pretty printable time string and `$sql_time` is the SQL timestamp string.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind changing you MySQL code you can just use MySQL's DATE_FORMAT() on the fetc:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(table_name.time_col, '%l:%i %p') AS myFriendlyDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the datetime functions built into MySQL?

DATE_FORMAT will allow you to manipulated it however you want.

Or any of the other functions may help you with it ...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format